# How to pop-up the Edit Products/MultiEdit modal window via Aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, opportunity-lineitem, navigation

The Edit Products/MultiEdit window is a pop-up in Lightning, so it cannot be shown by navigating to a particular URL, as was possible in Classic.

How can I pop-up this window via Aura Javascript code? I want to do this because I have a custom quick action + window, from which I want to navigate to the standard Edit Products/MultiEdit window.

This is the window that I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: is it custom component or standard component?

Comment: It is the standard window, accessed by the 'Edit Products' button in the OppLineItem related list of an Opportunity. It is also the standard action called MultiEdit.

Comment: if only we could create some hidden components like  force:listViewManagerGridForMultiEdit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard [force:recordEdit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordEdit/documentation) component from your aura component and pass the recordId.

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for. That will only let me edit one record. I am looking for a way to pop-up the special window that lets you edit all products in one opportunity.

Comment: In that case, you will have to create a custom component and use lightning:datatable, currently there is no standard way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/)? You can show and hide them with class `slds-hide`, pretty handy.

```
<div class="slds-hide">
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
  <div class="slds-modal__container">
    <header class="slds-modal__header">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
      </button>
      <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Modal Header</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
      <p>Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Cillum sunt ad dolore quis
        aute consequat ipsum magna exercitation reprehenderit magna. Tempor cupidatat consequat elit dolor adipisicing.</p>
      <p>Dolor eiusmod sunt ex incididunt cillum quis nostrud velit duis sit officia. Lorem aliqua enim laboris do dolor eiusmod officia. Mollit incididunt nisi consectetur esse laborum eiusmod pariatur proident. Eiusmod et adipisicing culpa deserunt nostrud
        ad veniam nulla aute est. Labore esse esse cupidatat amet velit id elit consequat minim ullamco mollit enim excepteur ea.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
```

Like that.
Than add and remove class `slds-hide` via JS

Comment: I want to pop-up the standard window. In Classic there is a URL for that, but I haven't found a way to do it in Lightning. I don't want to build Salesforce's own window from scratch.